# where are articles stored in joomla?

Tags: joomla

Sorry, this can be a newbie question.

I am going in Article Manager section of admin and I do see some articles but I want to know **which is the table which stores these articles**?

I simply see a lot of tables in DB but I am not able to guess which ones store the content from article manager.

Thanks.

Comment: See also: [Unified Content Model in Joomla 3.0](https://youtu.be/u2Naxcyz-dQ?t=447) by Mitch Pirtle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jos_content` is the table that holds the article. `jos_` is a place holder for your actual database table prefix - which might be `jos_` but isn't necessarily.

Comment: In newer Joomla versions there is a version history for articles. Can you tell were older versions are stored aswell or should I create a new question for this? I just found the `version` column in the database table `content` in Joomla 3.x

Comment: The content history is stored in `#__ucm_history`.

Answer (score 0):

If you using K2 extension for joomla, which is very popular, than your articles are stored into jos_k2_items. Prefix "jos" depends of what you typed in the time of the installation of joomla CMS system on your server.