# Where does Joomla store 'fulltext' of articles?

Tags: php, database, joomla, joomla3.0

Where does Joomla (3.3) store the 'fulltext' of articles? When I select all ("*") from the Joomla content table:

```
private function selectAllContent() {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select("*");
    $query->from($db->quoteName(array('#__contents')));
    $rows = $db->loadRowList();
    // ...
}
```

I find that the `fulltext` column is empty and the `introtext` column has a version of article text which has had some html markup removed, e.g. bullet lists. In Joomla admin, it is still possible to open the 'edit article' screen where the bullet point list markup is present. Where is it stored in the database?

I know there is a related question: **[where are articles stored in joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988042/where-are-articles-stored-in-joomla)** however, the answer for that question just says that the content table is where the article is stored, which does not quite address my problem. Many thanks if you can help out!

**Update**

I am still lost, so providing all the code and the process that results in 'lost' markup. I've used `print_r` to see everything being returned.

1. First, I create an article with a list, so the markup looks like:

   > Introductory example text
   >
   > 1. **Some item** plus more text here
   > 2. **Another item** plus more text here
2. The article is saved.
3. A module pulls all the articles (and all their content) from the database. The module code looks like this:

   ```
   // From the main module file:
   $helper = new modArticlesTableHelper;
   $articlesTable = $helper->getArticleContent($params);

   // From the module helper file:
   public function getArticleContent($params) {
       $result = $this->_getArticles();
       return "<div style=\"display:none;\">".print_r($result, true)."</div>";
   }

   private function _getArticles() {
       $db = JFactory::getDbo();
       $query = $db->getQuery(true);
       $query->select("*");
       $query->from($db->quoteName(array('#__contents')));
       $query->where($db->quoteName('catid')." = 16");
       $rows = $db->loadObj();
       return $rows;
   }
   ```
4. The result of which is simply echoed in the module template:

   ```
   echo $articlesTable;
   ```
5. If I then copy the markup that gets output by the module from the page displaying it, only this comes through:

   ```
   ["introtext"]=&gt;
   string(127) "Introductory example text 

   <strong>Some item</strong> plus more text here
   <strong>Another item</strong> plus more text here"
   ["fulltext"]=&gt;
   string(0) ""
   ```
6. So far, I don't see how a filter comes into play - it looks like it goes pretty directly from the database into `print_r`. However, when I then go to edit the article again, the markup remains:

> Introductory example text
>
> 1. **Some item** plus more text here
> 2. **Another item** plus more text here

Is it possible a filter stripped the list at some point here?

**Update 2**

If I add a Readmore break to the top of the joomla article, the following is returned, however, I don't believe that adding a readmore break to the top of each article is the correct way to go - seems like a hack!

```
["introtext"]=>
string(0) ""
["fulltext"]=>
string(164) "
<p>Introductory example text</p>
<ol>
<li><strong>Some item</strong> plus more text here</li>
<li><strong>Another item</strong> plus more text here</li>
</ol>"
```

Comment: Just on a side note, you don't need to put a single table in an array

Comment: If you can see the bullet points in the editor they must be stored in the DB, either in `introtext` or `fulltext` depending on if a `readmore` is in the article.

Comment: That is exactly what I had thought, although I am pulling out of the database with the above query and the list markup is not there.

Comment: how do you output the `introtext` afterwards? Maybe you're loosing the markup only there...

Comment: @wclear Are you still not sure of the answer? Save an article with intro  text and full text (just a couple of sentences0 and then paste what you find in the database in your questions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the exmaple database included with the Joomla 3.3 download, there is this entry for the #__content table (showing only a part of the `introtext` column):

```
<p>Here are some basic tips for working on your site.</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Joomla! has a "fr ... ge.</li>\r\n</ul>,
```

It contains the unordered list `<ul><li>`, and there is no other place in the SQL dump where the html markup for unordered lists can be found.

So the question is, on what facts are you basing your conclusion that:

> the introtext column has a version of article text which has had some
>   html markup removed, e.g. bullet lists.

For example: are you using any filtering functions when displaying the content?

Comment: Good point I will check out the filters now. I didn't think I was using any.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my question - it is still not obvious where the markup is being stored or stripped. Do the additional details in the question help identify the problem - maybe where the filters could be coming into play?

Comment: To debug problems, you should always try to minimize the number of layers you go through to find where you start to get unexpected results. You now have `joomla framework -> mysql -> joomla framework -> output`. It would be useful information to verify the actual database contents are correct with (assuming you use MySQL) the mysql command line or maybe Phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yes, I realise this - unfortunately going to have to chase up on access for that!

Comment: Just to be clear: with the exact same code, and the same article (but with a "more" link), you get the proper html markup in the `fulltext` property?

Comment: That's correct. I went back in, added readmore break to the very top of the article, and introtext and fulltext become:
["introtext"]=>
string(0) ""
["fulltext"]=>
string(164) "
<p>Introductory example text</p>
<ol>
<li><strong>Some item</strong> plus more text here</li>
<li><strong>Another item</strong> plus more text here</li>
</ol>"

Comment: One of these two must be false: 1. the data is stored in the DB without list markup. 2. The editor has knowledge of the list markup. (this is the reaon why you asked the question, obviously).  -- checking the actual entry in the DB would definitively answer nr 1. Since you don't have access (yet?), perhaps you could disable the WYSIWYG editor to get closer to nr. 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't put a "read more" break everything will be stored in introtext. If you put a read more then it will be split between  introtext and fulltext.  In other words, you only need fulltext if you are making that distinction. It's a little old fashioned, but that is the API from Joomla 1.0 which is pre JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, when it saves the article, it seems it must save the markup for things like lists in the article somewhere, else how would it serve them up when editing article later? So I am wondering where it has saved them. You are correct in that placing a read more break does indeed populate the fulltext field which then includes the list markup.

Comment: I'm really not understanding the question. The "text" includes all the markup.  Have you saved an article or two (maybe one with or without a readmore) and looked in the database?  You would have to have an extremely strict input filter set to remove list mark up.

Answer (score 2):

The markup is stored in the introtext/fulltext columns, there is no other place where just the markup is stored (would be a terrible idea to split them up). Do a `print_r($rows)` to see it's all there.

If you do not see it in your output the problem will be in the way you display it. Can you tell us how you do that?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated my question using print_r and a write up of the full process - it is still not obvious where the markup is being stored or stripped. Do the additional details in the question help?